# Is there a kind of docblock syntax for C? Does it work in STM32CubeIDE?

Tags: c, stm32cubeide

Let's say I have a function declaration:

```c
int32_t get_adc_reading();
```

I want to get any kind of help without peaking to the header file, so...

```c
/**
 * Gets a reading from ADC.
 * @retval 12-bit reading value.
 */
int32_t get_adc_reading();
```

The IDE seems to ignore the comment.
Is it even valid? Is "@retval" valid? Is it documented somewhere?

I try to Google it, but I get nothing.

Maybe I don't know how to ask. I coded mainly in C# before, I'm learning C now.

In C# it was normal I could put a `docblock` over any object to get IDE hint about that object. It worked in JavaScript in most editors I used. It worked in Python.

Does something like this even exists for C, and if so - where can I find a documentation for it?

Another weird thing I experience while learning C and using Google:

**"It looks like there aren't many great matches for your search"**

It's even weirder that I often find what I'm looking for much later and see it matches my query, however for some weird reason Google doesn't find it. Let's say my page contains words "plasma capacitor". It is about plasma capacitor. But it's somehow related to C. Let's say it's a C library. I enter "plasma capacitor" in Google and get the infuriating message. Then I'm looking for something completely different, but a little related, then I click on link there, and BLAM: "plasma capacitor" - it is there, but it's just not returned from search.

Comment: Doxygen, Javadoc, DocBlock are almost the same thing, in practice (well, for many people anyway). I don't know about your weirdly-named IDE, but your documentation block is just fine. CLion will highlight it, Eclipse will highlight it (possibly with a plugin or a default-off setting), VS Code will highlight it etc.

Comment: @einpoklum Stm32CubeIDE is based on Eclipse so it may be able to highlight. Tbh, I have never really paid attention to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unlike C# there isn't a standard comment documentation format for C or C++. The most used one is [Doxygen](https://www.doxygen.nl/index.html).

However most modern IDEs can display info about symbols gathered from comments, even if the comments don't follow a particular format.

Comment: The question is about C, not C++. The answer is correct for both, though. It should also be mentioned that as far as C (and C++) is concerned, anything inside a comment block is ignored. The compiler does not care about things like `@retval` or other expressions inside a comment block. Tools such as Doxygen etc. which interpret special expressions inside comment blocks have nothing to do with the C language itself.

Comment: @nielsen yes, C. I would think that it goes without saying that comments have no effect on the code.

Comment: Yet the OP seems to expect that the contents of the comment block will somehow be parsed according to rules defined by the language. Anyway, the answer is accepted so you are probably right :-)

Comment: I expected the content would be used for IDK, displaying some hints in the IDE. I noticed that in STM32CubeIDE the docblocks for `.c` files are displayed as hints, so well, maybe the syntax doesn't matter, but it's better than nothing.

Comment: @Harry OK, then the question is quite specific to STM32CubeIDE. From a quick test, I think STM32CubeIDE just displays the code around the beginning of the function definition including a preceding comment block. It does not look like it parses the comment.